# Calculate total only for employee's having both salary and bonus

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table which I need to make a calculated field with the total compensation for employees who have `count(distinct(pay_type)) > 1`.
When `count(distinct(pay_type)) > 1` is true I want the total amount in a column next to the amount column.
My approach was to use a window function along with some kind of `CASE` statement, but can't figure it out.

My current query is:

```
Select check_num, emp_id, name, pay_type, sum(amount) as amt
from employee_paystubs
group by check_num, emp_id, name, pay_type
order by check_num desc;
```

This is the resulting data:

| CHECK_NUM | EMP_ID | NAME | PAY_TYPE | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | JEFF | SALARY | 1500 |
| 02 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 |
| 03 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 |
| 04 | 2 | BOB | BONUS | 1000 |
| 05 | 5 | JAKE | SALARY | 1800 |
| 06 | 6 | MEGAN | SALARY | 1900 |

This is my desired output:

| CHECK_NUM | EMP_ID | NAME | PAY_TYPE | AMT | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | JEFF | SALARY | 1500 |  |
| 02 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 |  |
| 03 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 |  |
| 04 | 2 | BOB | BONUS | 1000 | 5000 |
| 05 | 5 | JAKE | SALARY | 1800 |  |
| 06 | 6 | MEGAN | SALARY | 1900 |  |

Thank you.

PS I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Case expression that checks for number of distinct PAY_TYPES (per EMP_ID) - and if it is > 1 (haave both: SALARY and BONUS) - fetches the Sum(AMT) in BONUS row....

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (CHECK_NUM, EMP_ID, NAME, PAY_TYPE, AMT) AS
        ( Select '01',  1,  'JEFF',  'SALARY',  1500 From Dual Union All
          Select '02',  2,  'BOB',   'SALARY',  2000 From Dual Union All
          Select '03',  2,  'BOB',   'SALARY',  2000 From Dual Union All
          Select '04',  2,  'BOB',   'BONUS',   1000 From Dual Union All
          Select '05',  5,  'JAKE',  'SALARY',  1800 From Dual Union All
          Select '06',  6,  'MEGAN', 'SALARY',  1900 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select    t.*,
          Case When Count(Distinct PAY_TYPE) Over(Partition By EMP_ID) > 1 And PAY_TYPE = 'BONUS'
               Then Sum(AMT) Over(Partition By EMP_ID) 
          End "NEW_COL"
From        tbl t
Order By  CHECK_NUM
```

```sql
/*     R e s u l t :
CHECK_NUM     EMP_ID NAME  PAY_TYPE        AMT    NEW_COL
--------- ---------- ----- -------- ---------- ----------
01                 1 JEFF  SALARY         1500           
02                 2 BOB   SALARY         2000           
03                 2 BOB   SALARY         2000           
04                 2 BOB   BONUS          1000       5000
05                 5 JAKE  SALARY         1800           
06                 6 MEGAN SALARY         1900             */
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to handle multiple `BONUS` lines for an employee, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (CHECK_NUM, EMP_ID, NAME, PAY_TYPE, AMT) AS
SELECT '01', 1, 'JEFF',  'SALARY', 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 2, 'BOB',   'SALARY', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 2, 'BOB',   'SALARY', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '04', 2, 'BOB',   'BONUS',  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '05', 5, 'JAKE',  'SALARY', 1800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '06', 6, 'MEGAN', 'SALARY', 1900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '07', 7, 'AMY',   'SALARY', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '08', 7, 'AMY',   'BONUS',  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '09', 7, 'AMY',   'SALARY', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10', 7, 'AMY',   'BONUS',  1000 FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to output the total amount for all bonus lines then:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE pay_type
       WHEN 'BONUS'
       THEN SUM(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id)
       END AS newcol
FROM   table_name t
```

Outputs:

| CHECK_NUM | EMP_ID | NAME | PAY_TYPE | AMT | NEWCOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | JEFF | SALARY | 1500 | *null* |
| 02 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 03 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 04 | 2 | BOB | BONUS | 1000 | 5000 |
| 05 | 5 | JAKE | SALARY | 1800 | *null* |
| 06 | 6 | MEGAN | SALARY | 1900 | *null* |
| 07 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 08 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 6000 |
| 09 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 10 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 6000 |

If you want to output the cumulative total then:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE pay_type
       WHEN 'BONUS'
       THEN SUM(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_num)
       END AS newcol
FROM   table_name t
```

Outputs:

| CHECK_NUM | EMP_ID | NAME | PAY_TYPE | AMT | NEWCOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | JEFF | SALARY | 1500 | *null* |
| 02 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 03 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 04 | 2 | BOB | BONUS | 1000 | 5000 |
| 05 | 5 | JAKE | SALARY | 1800 | *null* |
| 06 | 6 | MEGAN | SALARY | 1900 | *null* |
| 07 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 08 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 3000 |
| 09 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 10 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 6000 |

If you want to restart counting from 0 after each bonus then:

```sql
SELECT check_num,
       emp_id,
       name,
       pay_type,
       amt,
       newcol
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY check_num) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (emp_id)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (
    check_num,
    name,
    pay_type,
    amt,
    0 AS total,
    0 AS last_bonus,
    0 AS newcol
  )  
  RULES (
    total[rn]      = amt[cv(rn)]
                     + COALESCE(total[cv(rn) - 1], 0),
    last_bonus[rn] = CASE pay_type[cv(rn)]
                     WHEN 'BONUS'
                     THEN total[cv(rn)]
                     ELSE COALESCE(last_bonus[cv(rn) - 1], 0)
                     END,
    newcol[rn]     = CASE pay_type[cv(rn)]
                     WHEN 'BONUS'
                     THEN last_bonus[cv(rn)] - COALESCE(last_bonus[cv(rn) - 1], 0)
                     END
  )
```

Which outputs:

| CHECK_NUM | EMP_ID | NAME | PAY_TYPE | AMT | NEWCOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | JEFF | SALARY | 1500 | *null* |
| 06 | 6 | MEGAN | SALARY | 1900 | *null* |
| 02 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 03 | 2 | BOB | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 04 | 2 | BOB | BONUS | 1000 | 5000 |
| 05 | 5 | JAKE | SALARY | 1800 | *null* |
| 07 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 08 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 3000 |
| 09 | 7 | AMY | SALARY | 2000 | *null* |
| 10 | 7 | AMY | BONUS | 1000 | 3000 |

*Note: You can add a check for `COUNT(DISTINCT pay_type) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id) > 1` to the `CASE` expression if you want but, for your sample data, if there is a `BONUS` row then there always appears to be a `SALARY` row so it appears to be sufficient to just look for a `BONUS` row rather than counting all the pay types.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/On7DV3IS)